# How can I turn my email off for the night? (iOS)

Tags: ios, notifications

I would like to be able to easily turn on and off notifications for a particular app. I have my reasons for this, and if you'd like to know them you can check the edit history, but please keep responses to the topic of how I can do this, not whether I should want to.

There seem to be a couple of options for this, but neither is ideal.

Firstly, I could turn on "do not disturb" mode for the periods when I'd like the notifications turned off. This will block notifications from other apps, so it's not what I want.

Secondly, I could go to Settings -> Notification Centre -> [my app] and toggle "Show on Lock Screen". This doesn't seem to be something Siri can do for me, and it's something I want to do very often, so going this deep in the menu hierarchy is inconvenient.

Is there a more convenient way to toggle notifications for a particular app?

Comment: I've removed the comments, please let's assume that the OP has his reasons for the question.

Answer (score 1):

As for the current version of iOS (7).
No, there is not. Apple only offers the Do Not Disturb feature and the settings for notification center which are *currently* not controllable by Siri.